# Updating table values with value from another table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to update a blank column with values in another table with the same column name. I've written a statement to get those values

```
SELECT p.[ID]
      ,[PatientID]
      ,p.[ClinicID]
      ,[CurrentPlanNumber],
        pin.ClinicId
  FROM [ProductCheckout] p
  inner join Patients pin 
  on p.PatientID=pin.Id
```

When I try to update the columns I get an error:

Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

```
UPDATE [ProductCheckout]
   SET ClinicId = (SELECT p.[ID]
      ,[PatientID]
      ,p.[ClinicID]
      ,[CurrentPlanNumber],
        pin.ClinicId
  FROM [ProductCheckout] p
  inner join Patients pin 
  on p.PatientID=pin.Id)
```

Comment: You are updating only `ClinicId`, then why are you selecting so many values??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 UPDATE pin
   SET pin.ClinicId = p.[ID]
  FROM [ProductCheckout] pin
  inner join Patients p
  on pin.PatientID=p.Id
```

Answer (score 1):

Update using `JOIN`.

**Query**

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.ClinidId = t2.ClinicId
FROM [ProductCheckout] t1
JOIN Patients t2
ON t1.PatientID = t2.Id
WHERE t1.ClinidId IS NULL;
```